# Silence Rails logging in before blocks with RSpec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

It is possible to call `Rails.logger.silence` for the duration of every `before` block in the spec suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is to monkey patch RSpec's `before` implementation. Unfortunately, simple attempts to do this run afoul of RSpec's `let` implementation in ways that I have not been able to understand. Perhaps one the RSpec wizards could shed light on this one way or another.

Specifically, the following seems to work for at least some cases as long as you do not use `let` or `let!`:

```
module RSpec::Core::Hooks
  alias_method :old_before, :before
  def before(type = :each, &block)
    old_before(type) {Rails.logger.silence block}
  end
end
```